# I'm getting error for user field in registration form

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, thymeleaf

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
> target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:153)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]

HTML

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/process_register}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    
                    <h4 class="mb-4 pb-3">Sign Up</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">Username
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" class="form-style">
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group mt-2">Password
                        <input type="password" th:field="*{password}"  class="form-style">
                    </div>
...</form>
```

Controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());

        return "signup_form";
    }



@PostMapping("/process_register")
public String processRegister(Model theModel, User user) {
    
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
    
    user.setPassword(encodedPassword);
    userService.save(user);
    return "Wellcome";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your forgot to add `user` object to Model in a controller method that landed you on this form page. To make sure that doesn't happen best is to just add model attributing method to controller that always takes care of this:

```
@ModelAttribute("user") 
public User user() { 
  return new User(); 
}
```

Also please make sure User class have getters, setters and no arg constructor defined - that is important for Thymeleaf

Comment: Thanks, that was helpfull!